# Using preg_replace_callback with shortcodes

Tags: php, preg-replace-callback

I'm trying to implement short codes on my website to make publishing easier. What i got so far look like this:

```
$text = "[button]Hello[button] [input]holololo[input]";
$shortcodes = Array( 'button' => '<button>{content}</button>', 'input' => '<input type="text" value="{content}" />' );
$text = preg_replace_callback('(\[([a-z]+?)\](.+?)\[\\\1\])', function ($matches){ 
   if ($shortcodes[$matches[1]]){ 
            return str_replace('{content}', $matches[2], $shortcodes[$matches[1]]); 
   }else{
     return $matches[0]; 
   } 
}, $text);
echo $text;
```

What i want this to echo is: `<button>Hello</button> <input type="text" value="holololo" />`

But instead it just echo's out: [button]Hello[button] [input]holololo[input]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things. First, your regex is like this:

```
'(\[([a-z]+?)\](.+?)\[\\\1\])'
```

You don't want to escape the slash before the 1, otherwise you are literally searching for "\1" rather than the backreference. So that should be:

```
'(\[([a-z]+?)\](.+?)\[\1\])'
```

Also:

```
function ($matches) {
```

You try to refer to `$shortcodes` in your function. However, that is defined outside the function, so it has no access to it. You must explicitly pass any non-global variables to a function. When dealing with an anonymous function like this, use the `use` instruction, so your function definition should look like this:

```
function ($matches) use ($shortcodes) {
```

Making those two simple changes gave me this output:

```
<button>Hello</button>
<input type="text" value="holololo">
```

Comment: It won't show just a button if i only have the tags like this: [button][button], and i'm not that good in php, could you help me?

Comment: @Murillio4 That's actually not a PHP issue, just a slight change in your regex: `(.+?)` means *one or more* of any character. If you change it to `(.*?)` that means *zero or more* of any character. In other words, that allows it to match nothing at all. Note, however, that'll give you a button with no text.